# Invariance of probabilistic model wrt given moment

Tags: probability, distributions, stochastic-processes, invariance

Is there an established notion of sets within families of probability distributions which are invariant with respect to a given moment? E.g. let's say that we are looking into a family of parametric probability distributions and fix an expression for their mean as a function of the parameters: how can we find all parameterisations in this family that yield this specified mean? In an approximate sense, how can we find distributions/stochastic processes so that all their realisations are close in value to the empirical mean of a given distribution/stochastic process? I think this question is conceptually related to the maximum entropy problem in exponential family distributions, but I haven't found works beyond that.

Comment: Note that a statistic is a sample quantity while if you fix the mean of a probability distribution you're fixing a parameter (a population quantity). Could you clarify the intent of your question?

Answer (score 1):

For many families of distributions, it is quite simple to reparameterise the distribution directly in terms of the central moments.  This is especially simple when the moment equations are simple functions of the (standard) parameters, and the inversion is in closed form.  For example, one can quite easily reparameterise the gamma distribution in terms of the mean $\mu$ and the variance $\sigma^2$.  Once you do this, the parameter sets corresponding to fixed moments are trivial.